# How can I disable access for my flask app for people using a VPN?

Tags: python, flask

Some people are trying to access my site (I believe they are hackers), and when I blocked their IP, I noticed they used VPNs to access my site again. Is there any way I can prevent people using a VPN from accessing my site?

Any help will be VERY appreciated, I've been trying this for so long.

This is how I am blocking IP addresses:

```
ip_ban_list = ['130.180.2.129', '109.40.2.120', '37.120.205.148', '109.201.143.78', '37.120.132.76', '37.120.132.66', '185.244.215.134', '109.42.1.48', '109.42.2.193', '172.67.16.210']

@app.before_request
def block_method():
  ip = request.environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
  if ip in ip_ban_list:
    abort(403)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some of the ip adresses of the VPN providers are known. Quick googling returned me something like this https://github.com/ejrv/VPNs but I recommmend digging further.
This quora post might be useful as well https://www.quora.com/How-do-some-websites-know-Im-using-a-VPN-How-can-I-go-around-this#:~:text=While%20using%20a%20VPN%2C%20your,you%20are%20using%20a%20VPN.

Overall your method is decent, you might scale it somehow to process all the IPs of the VPN providers

Comment: Yes, well, I know how to block IPs, I did that, but when people use VPNs, they can use different IP addresses, and access my site again.

Answer (score 0):

VPN providers do their best to hide that their users use VPN. Every IP list will be outdated soon and if you find out a method to identify VPN / Proxy they will find way around it.

If you have a system with limited number of users, blocking all IP addresses but whitelisting ones you want to access is effective approach. But process to start using your system is harder. Of course, you can automate that process a bit, for example by adding IPs to whitelist when user register his account. But that mean that your users needs fixed IP address and consumers does not have that option. So this approach works only in B2B solutions.

Other approach would be geoblocking. You can allow access only from IP addresses which are from certain country or region. But this kind of limitations are easily worked around with VPN / Proxies.

Third approach would be to dynamically add IPs to blacklist if you notice some suspicious behavior. Easy example would be if you notice that there is multiple failed login attemps from certain IP, you block it. And there can be some other sings of malicious traffic which can trigger your dynamic ban. It would be worth to make these dynamic bans temporary, so they would expire in a few hours. This method does not identify VPN, but may prevent hacking attemps.

Answer (score 0):

I add the entries to the database for each page entry. Think like a numerator
Then I check with pandas that there are a suspicious number of logins. If that IP address logs in, I hold it with time.sleep(6000) and send it to the 403 page.
I also save blocklist.conf and block it from nginx.